# Rails and ruby class, instance variables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new in ruby on rails and have a little confusion on the following code

```
module Comment
  class CommentScore < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'comment_scores'

    # Associations
    belongs_to :provider_account

    # Scopes
    scope :by_provider_account_id, lambda { |provider_account_id| where(provider_account_id: provider_account_id) }

    # Instance methods
    def set
      return unless self.valid?
      return if unsettable?
      self.positive_count = provider_account.comment.total(:positive)
      self.total          = provider_account.comment.total(:all)
      self.score          = decimal
      self.save!
    end

    def decimal
      positive_count.to_d / total.to_d
    end
  end
end
```

from my studies, I learned that if the 'self' keyword is used inside a method, it will just actually call a method like in this example, self.positive_count, calls the method 'positive_count' which in rails, means the table column named 'positive_count'.

So I got a bit confused in the 'decimal' method, it just use 'positive_count' without the self? Isn't it a local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord will define getters and setters for each field in your model, eg. in this case you will get `positive_count` and `positive_count=` defined.

You can call the getter easily, like you are doing in your decimal method. However, to call the setter like you are in your `set` method, you need to use `self` - otherwise you will simply set a local variable in that method with the value, instead of calling the setter.

Comment: simple and concise. Didn't know activerecord defines getter and setter automatically. When I read that it all just made sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When there is such local variable as `positive_count`, then the form `positive_count` without the period and arguments will be interpreted as a local variable. If not, then it will be interpreted as a method. However,  methods of the form `foo=` are obligatorily private.

Answer (score 0):

Based on context and what methods have been defined, Ruby will try and determine if you're making a method call or reading from or assigning to a variable. Unlike other languages where local variables must be defined in advance (`int total`), or where variables are specified with a different syntax (`$int`), Ruby has a syntax that's a lot more stripped down. This can lead to some ambiguity.

If there's a method defined with a particular name, like `decimal` or there's a method that accepts values, such as `total=`, then a method call will be made when these are referenced. Otherwise it's presumed they're variables.

Use of `self` avoids ambiguity and forces a method call. It's often used to be sure there's no risk of creating a variable by accident.

Consider the following:

```
def example
  total = 50
end
```

Is `total` a variable, or is there a method called `total=` that can be used instead? It's not clear from this short example. By default Ruby will treat that as a variable.

Now if you have a column in the database called `total`, this is discovered *after* the original model code has been loaded. At that time there was no method called `total=`. This method is created dynamically after the first instance of that model is instantiated. This is where you get the `self`-dot notation showing up:

```
def example
  self.total = 50
end
```

This ensures you're assigning to the attribute and not creating a local variable by mistake.